# Twitter card on subdomain

Tags: twitter, subdomain, twitter-card

i have put the meta tag of image source on my domain, for example: http://kawantaman.com

so i put the meta tag of image source on my subdomain also, for example: http://kawantaman.com/questioner

the problem is, when i shared to twitter my subdomain (http://kawantaman.com/questioner), but the image preview of card is redirected to core domain (http://kawantaman.com).

how to share card based on meta tag of my subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That URL (`/questioner`) redirects to the main top-level domain in the browser and when using curl, so when a user clicks a link to it on Twitter, the same thing happens. You'll need to fix your site setup.